# problems running image_transport rosjava tutorial

Tags: ros, android-gingerbread, rosjava, android, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried using multiple version of rosjava (from debian and building straight from source).  First question is, which is the preferred method (the method that will give the least amount of problems).

I also downloaded rosjava.android source and tried compiling, android_gingerbread, but get an error referring to missing the rosserial_java package.  Not being able to compile rosjava_android seems to be preventing me from running the image_tranport tutorial because when I import the project into Eclipse, I receive an error referring to a missing gen folder within the android_gingerbread project.

Is there a precompiled debian version of rosjava.android available?  Also, are there reliable step-by-step instruction available that show what packages to download and how to succesfully run the rosjava tutorials within Eclipse?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11291/problems-running-image_transport-rosjava-tutorial/) by [guzza](https://answers.ros.org/users/374/guzza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've successfully gotten rosjava and android to work by following [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/2178/rosjavajar-missing-certain-packages#3713).

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2011-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0